# C# await on a List<T> Count

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I am upgrading some legacy *WinForms* code and I am trying to figure out what the "right way" as of **.NET 4.6.1** to refactor the following.

The current code is doing a tight `while(true)` loop while checking a `bool` property.  This property puts a `lock()` on a generic `List<T>` and then returns true if it has no items (`list.Count == 0`).

The loop has the dreaded `Application.DoEvents()` in it to make sure the message pump continues processing, otherwise it would lock up the application.

Clearly, this needs to go.

My confusion is how to start a basic refactoring where it still can check the queue length, while executing on a thread and not blowing out the CPU for no reason.  A delay between checks here is fine, even a "long" one like 100ms+.

I was going to go with an approach that makes the method async and lets a Task run to do the check:

```
await Task.Run(() => KeepCheckingTheQueue());
```

Of course, this keeps me in the situation of the method needing to ... loop to check the state of the queue.

Between the waiting, awaiting, and various other methods that can be used to move this stuff to the thread pool ... any suggestion on how best to handle this?

Comment: just start a thread for the processing and rise an event when finished. you can handle the event and no need for loop->checkstatus. or put to a [Background Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) and use `RunWorkerCompleted` event

Comment: Could you replace the List with, say, a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

Comment: Is replacing the list type possible? Can you not have your own class that implements `IList<T>`, is backed by a real list, and triggers your desired behaviour when `Remove` drops the count to 0 (or `Clear` is called)

Comment: @IanMercer I can replace the `List` to remove the `lock()` (I'm not sure why there is a lock, the code uses no threading ... unless the original dev thought this was required for the DoEvents looping?).  My real problem is I need to move this `while(true) -> check -> DoEvents()` loop on the UI thread as cleanly as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I need is how to best "poll' a boolean member (or property) while freeing the UI, without the DoEvents().

The answer you're asking for:

```
private async Task WaitUntilAsync(Func<bool> func)
{
  while (!func())
    await Task.Delay(100);
}

await WaitUntilAsync(() => list.Count == 0);
```

However, polling like this is a really poor approach. If you can describe the actual problem your code is solving, then you can get better solutions.

For example, if the list represents some queue of work, and your code is wanting to asynchronously wait until it's done, then this can be better coded using an explicit signal (e.g., `TaskCompletionSource<T>`) or a true producer/consumer queue (e.g., TPL Dataflow).

Comment: This is the approach I was envisioning (better than what I had, but agreed, still bad).

To better describe the issue, this is an "animation" system for WinForms, sort of a "fake WPF" ordeal.  The queue holds a list of controls to be animated, so that they can be done in parallel.  The `DoEvents()` checking that `Control` queue (`List<>`) is allowing these animations to "run in parallel" while still pumping messages.  I am trying to avoid a total, complete refactor due to time constraints and large source.

The `bool` property is essentially "all done" and returns `queue.Length ==0'.

Comment: @Patrick: Consider using `Task.WhenAll`, a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, or an `AsyncCountdownEvent`. I have an ACE available [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination).

Comment: Thanks!  I will take a look.  It's funny that you mention `TaskCompletionSource` as that is the MSDN tab that I currently have open.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally never a good idea for client code to worry about locking a collection (or sprinkling your code with `lock()` blocks everywhere) before querying it.  Best to encapsulate that complexity out.

Instead I recommend using one of the .NET concurrent collections such as [`ConcurrentBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx).  No need for creating a `Task` which is somewhat expensive.

If your collection does not change much you might want to consider one of the **immutable** thread-safe collections such as `ImmutableList<>`.

**EDIT:**  Upon reading your comments I suggest you use a WinForms `Timer`;  `OnApplicationIdle` or `BackgroundWorker`.  The problem with `async` is that you still need to periodically call it.  Using a timer or app idle callback offers the benefit of using the GUI thread.

Comment: The problem here is that the `lock()` is the least of my concerns, as I already expect there is absolutely no use for it, as the current code is not multi-threaded!  What I need is how to best "poll' a boolean member (or property) while freeing the UI, without the DoEvents().

Comment: If it's not multi-threaded then why was `lock()` added in the first place.  Considering that `List<>.Count` returns immediately why the need for a background job or `Task`?

Comment: I'm am not sure exactly why yet.  But there is no explicit threading code being used and this not a library used by any third-party.  Initial thought is the developer may have thought this was needed after adding a DoEvents() but, why?  No idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, you could start a background thread or a background worker. Or maybe even a timer.

Those are executed in a different thread, and are therefore not locking the execution of your other form related code. `Invoke` the original thread if you have to perform actions on the UI thread.

I would also recommend to prevent locking as much as possible, for example by doing a check before actually locking:

```
if (list.Count == 0)
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            // execute your code here
        }
    }
}
```

That way you are only locking if you really need to and you avoid unnecessary blocking of your application.

Comment: I have written way too much multi-threaded WinForms code using threads, the thread pool, and the `BackgroundWorkers`.  But wouldn't that approach still need to tight loop and check the `bool` and then return as completed?  I don't really want `Thread.Sleep()` in here either, to relax the CPU between checks, but I'll do it if that's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after here is the ability to `await Task.Yield()`.

```
class TheThing {
  private readonly List<int> _myList = new List<int>();

  public async Task WaitForItToNotBeEmpty() {
    bool hadItems;
    do {
      await Task.Yield();
      lock (_myList) // Other answers have touched upon this locking concern
        hadItems = _myList.Count != 0;
    } while (!hadItems);
  }
  // ...
}
```